# (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO1nP.png) the errors pic

When I run the spring boot application, I get this error, (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt is in unnamed module of loader 'app'). I try to follow other article but still not get the answer.

I want the html page shows the sharepoint list page in my web page.

```
Controller page

    @GetMapping("/leave")
    public List<LeaveRequestDetail> leave() throws IOException {
        return dao.getAll(getSharepointClient());
    }   
    
Dao page
public List<LeaveRequestDetail> getAll(

        SharepointClient<Request> sharepointClient
      )
        throws IOException {
        JsonElement element = sharepointClient.items(
          leaveDetailService.LEAVES_SITE_NAME,
          leaveDetailService.LEAVE_REQ_LIST_ID
        );
        return _getListFromJsonElement(sharepointClient, element, true, false);
      }

Controller page
  public interface LeaveRequestDetailRepo extends BaseRepo<LeaveRequestDetail> {

public LeaveRequestDetail findById(String id);

public Optional<LeaveRequestDetail> getById(String id);

public List<LeaveRequestDetail> findAll();

public LeaveRequestDetail deleteById(String id);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public LeaveRequestDetail save(LeaveRequestDetail leave);

}
```

Errors:
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.5.jar:5.7.5]

Comment: You should read the complete error. The part you have cited is not the full error.

Comment: It shows this line caused the error in the BaseController..                                                            @ModelAttribute(value = "user")
   protected Jwt getUserInfo() {
     Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder
       .getContext()
       .getAuthentication();
     Jwt oidcUser = (Jwt) auth.getPrincipal();
     return oidcUser;
   }

Comment: Every exception has a type. Which type does your exception have? Then, if the printout is like `SomeException: …`, every thing after the colon is the exception message. It did not start with the first `(`. I could guess that you have a `ClassCastException` but why should I? Do we really expect to much when we expect a *complete exception* and not just some arbitrary fragment of it?

Comment: I get the error like this 
class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Comment: Don’t write that in a comment. As said, include the full exception. In the question. And post the relevant code that produces the exception. Again *in the question*. I don’t see the code of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76421755/java-lang-string-is-in-module-java-base-of-loader-bootstrap-org-springframew#comment134756043_76421755) anywhere in the question.

Comment: I posted the errors in the question. This is the error I get now after I click the website. In the website message shows Message class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt is in unnamed module of loader 'app').

Comment: The code containing the `getPrincipal()` call and the problematic type cast still is not contained in the question. And instead of adding the `ClassCastException` of your question, you posted an entirely different `AccessDeniedException`. Are you serious?

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie for Java and in the console, it starts with this error.. I try find ClassCastException in the console but haven't find any related to ClassCastException.